# Beppo Levi theorem

Tags: measure-theory

In Beppo Levi's theorem, we require that the sequence of measurable functions are $\text{increasing}$. However, does a convergence result for integrals exist which deals with arbitrary sequences of measurable functions  $(u_j)$ (as long as they are positive) that are not necessarily increasing, with $u$ being the $\liminf, $\limsup, or even the $\lim$ of these functions?

Or are such results derivable from Beppo Levi? One of these are Fatou's Lemma, but I am less interested in inequalities. Are there others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the Dominated Convergence Theorem, of course:

> Let $(f_n)$ be integrable, $\lvert f_n \rvert <g$, $g$ integrable. Then if $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e., then
>   $$ \lim_n \int f_n = \int f. $$

I assume you know about that, but want something with fewer conditions.

Presumably you're looking for something a bit more like this: there is an extension of Fatou's lemma that tells you when it is an equality. It was discovered by Lieb and Brézis, who call it the *missing term in Fatou's lemma*:

> Let $(f_n) \subset L^p$ be integrable with uniformly bounded integrals, $\int f_n<C$. Suppose also that $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e. Then
>   $$ \lim_{n} \int \left\lvert \lvert f_n \rvert^p-\lvert f_n-f \rvert^p- \lvert f \rvert^p \right\rvert = 0. $$

You can find the proof of it in Lieb and Loss's *Analysis*, currently available [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Eb_7oRorXJgC&lpg=PA20&ots=HEzMxu10Pl&dq=missing%20term%20in%20fatou&pg=PA21#v=onepage&q=missing%20term%20in%20fatou&f=false). It does require use of the Dominated Convergence Theorem in the proof (which is one reason I mentioned it above), and convexity of $ t \mapsto \lvert t \rvert^p$.

Comment: Thanks. In the DCT, I was wondering ... what is an counter-example where the equality does not hold due to $g$ not being integrable?

Comment: There's a silly sort of example like taking $f_n(x) = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$, the indicator function on $[n,n+1]$, on $\mathbb{R}$ with normal Lebesgue measure. Clearly $\int f_n = 1$ for every $n$, but $f_n \to 0$ pointwise, so
$$ \lim_n \int f_n = 1 \neq 0 = \int f. $$

Comment: I was hoping to see a counterexample where $f$ plays the role of $g$. That is, $|f_n| \le f$, and $f$ is not necessarily integrable. In your example, this is naturally not the case. Does such a counter-example exist? I'm thinking maybe both sides of the equality become $\infty$, so we get $\infty = \infty$ in the case where $\int f \ d \mu = \infty$, and so we could say this version of DCT holds when we allow $\infty = \infty$?

Comment: I can't think of an example off the top of my head. You're welcome to ask a separate question, though.