# convergence in $L^p, p >2$ and convergence in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions in $L^p, p>2$, and let $f$ be also in $L^p$.

In order to show $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$, I would need to show $\int |f_n - f|^p \to 0 $. Instead of showing that, would it be sufficient to show $|f_n|^p \to |f|^p$ in $L^1$?

Comment: No. What if $f_n = -f$ for all $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $f_n = -f$ for all $n$, then $|f_n|^p$ will not converge to $|f|^p$ in $L^1$ unless $f$ vanishes almost everywhere.

On the other hand, if $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere and $|f_n|^p \to |f|^p$ in $L^1$, then $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$. This is a result of Brezis and Lieb.

Comment: Could you give me the reference for the result by Brezis and Lieb that you mentioned?

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452778/beppo-levi-theorem/1452813#1452813

Comment: Thanks for your answer and pointing me to the reference

Answer (score 1):

If $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $\int|f_n|^p \to \int|f|^p,$ then $\int|f_n-f|^p \to 0.$ (Note that the assumption is, at least on the surface, weaker than assuming $|f_n|^p \to \int|f|^p$ in $L^1.$) Hint for proof: Apply Fatou's Lemma to $2^{p-1}(|f_n|^p+|f|^p)-|f_n-f|^p.$